# MFC ribbon interface gives assert failure when localizing app

Tags: c++, localization, mfc, ribbon, assert

I have an MFC-based app that uses the Office 2007 ribbon interface. MFC is statically linked.

I'm trying to add Japanese localization. I have the localized resources in a separate DLL. I'm loading the resource DLL at the beginning of `InitInstance`:

```
VERIFY(hRes = LoadLibrary(_T("JapaneseLang.dll")));
if(hRes)
    AfxSetResourceHandle(hRes);
```

This causes an assert failure at `CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::OnUpdateSystemColors`

```
#if !defined _AFXDLL
        TRACE(_T("\r\nImportant: to enable the Office 2007 look in static link,\r\n"));
        TRACE(_T("include afxribbon.rc from the RC file in your project.\r\n\r\n"));
        ASSERT(FALSE);
#endif
```

But I do have `afxribbon.rc` included in the rc files of both the DLL and the EXE.

---

I also found a [similar question asked at tech-archive.net](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/2008-06/msg00225.html) and a [possible solution](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/2008-06/msg00230.html) is outlined there

> Now i find the error location. this shoule be a bug of new mfc
>   version.
>
> In the CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007 ,when the style is changing , the 
>   function SetStyle of CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007 auto call FreeLibrary
>   to  free the dll, so the error happend.
>
> Now i derived a class from CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007 and add a
>   static function to set the member variable m_bAutoFreeRes , by  doing
>   this the application can run correctly; see bellow.
>
> class CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007 : public
>   CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007 {
>   DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007) public:
>   CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007(); virtual
>   ~CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007();
>
> static void SetAutoFreeRes(BOOL bAutoFree = FALSE) { m_bAutoFreeRes =
>   bAutoFree; } };

---

But I have trouble understanding what exactly causes the problem, and how this solution works. Also I'm not sure if it is a correct solution. Does anyone know what exactly causes this problem, and how the solution works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how the solution works. I need to set `m_bAutoFreeRes` to false after each call to `CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::SetStyle`.

```
class CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007 : public CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007)
public:
    CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007();
    virtual ~CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007();

    static void SetAutoFreeRes(BOOL bAutoFree = FALSE)
    {
        m_bAutoFreeRes = bAutoFree;
    }
};
```

and then when switching between the themes

```
    switch (m_nAppLook)
    {
    case ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_OFF_2007_BLUE:
        CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::SetStyle (CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::Office2007_LunaBlue);
        CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007::SetAutoFreeRes(FALSE);
        break;

    case ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_OFF_2007_BLACK:
        CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::SetStyle (CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::Office2007_ObsidianBlack);
        CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007::SetAutoFreeRes(FALSE);
        break;

    case ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_OFF_2007_SILVER:
        CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::SetStyle (CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::Office2007_Silver);
        CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007::SetAutoFreeRes(FALSE);
        break;

    case ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_OFF_2007_AQUA:
        CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::SetStyle (CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::Office2007_Aqua);
        CMFCVisualExtManagerOffice2007::SetAutoFreeRes(FALSE);
        break;
    }
```